# Luggage shipping service within Copenhagen Kastrup airport

Tags: luggage, airports, hotels, shipping, cph

I am planning to fly to Copenhagen Kastrup airport in Denmark with 2 large suitcases. (Maybe I should say "huge and heavy").

So it'd be very tiring to carry these by myself to my hotel. I was wondering if there is a luggaging shipping service located within the airport. Is such service available at the airport? If not, what would be my best option? I will be staying at Vedbæk.

Comment: How will you yourself be getting up to Vedbæk?

Comment: By train. So it'd be very inconvenient to carry two huge suitcases.

Comment: Is it a direct train? Only getting between the arrivals and the platform at the airport with heavy luggage isn't too bad

Comment: @Gagravarr Right, but carrying two large suitcases is very inconvinient (for example going to toilet), so I thought I would ship them if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you have two options:

1. Get a porter to take you baggage from the conveyor to the train. [Here is an example of a service that does this.](http://www.porterservice.dk/default.asp?ID=2&groupID=2)  The train station is inside the airport so it's not bad. Then get a taxi at the other end, and maybe a station porter to help you.
2. Get an airport porter to the taxi rank (the service linked to above will do this too) and have a taxi take you all the way to your hotel. It's under 20km so it won't be extortionate, only expensive. I doubt it would be more than getting your luggage shipped separately.